# Syncronize a function with two different files from different folders in bash

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop

I am trying to synchronize a function with two arrays of files. This is what I have done:

```
path_c=/dir1/*fa 
path_b=/dir2/*rem

for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo ${path_c[$i]} ${path_b[$i]};  done
```

I have 4 files in directory 1 and 4 files in directory 2. The files have the same name but different format

Does anybody have a good solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance

Example: I have the following files

```
dir1/dog.fa 
dir1/cat.fa
dir2/dog.rem
dir2/cat.rem
```

They are supposed to work at the same time with the function *macrame*

```
macrame -a dir1/dog.fa -b dir2/dog.rem
macrame -a dir1/cat.fa -b dir2/cat.rem
```

I am trying to do a loop because I have hundreds of files in both directories

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I updated the question hope that now will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Neither variable is an array.

```
path_c=(/dir1/*fa)
path_b=(/dir2/*rem)
```

However, you *probably* don't need the arrays, and can use the following:

```
for c_file in /dir1/*.fa; do
  b_file=/dir2/$(basename "$c_file" .fa).rem
  echo "$c_file" "$b_file"
done
```

Comment: I can not use this because the *.rem files are in another directory and I can not mix them.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. Will fix.

Comment: It worked! And now I understand more how bash works...Thank you!